# Nested UITableViews: a way to scroll both the outer vertical UITableView and a child horizontal UITableView at the same time?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, nested, uitouch

When you're working with an atypical nested UITableViews setup - where you have an outer vertical UITableView that hosts 90° rotated UITableViews (see: [Looking for a UI library to present Data horizontaly in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179683/looking-for-a-ui-library-to-present-data-horizontaly-in-ios) ):
is there a way to make iOS process vertical *and* horizontal touches *at the same time*?

I found that iOS is very clever in processing touches:
horizontal touches make the relevant horizontal UITableView scroll, while a vertical swipe makes the outer UITableView scroll. Perfect.

Only, I'd love to be able to move my finger diagonally and see the outer UITableView *and* the inner UITableView scroll at the same time.

I tried a few approaches (playing with canCancelContentTouches, delaysContentTouches, and touch messages) but I haven't found a way to make this happen.

EDIT:
Here's a XCode4 project that shows this behavior: http://marcanton.io/other/stackoverflow/nestedtableviews.zip

EDIT:
I submitted this issue to Apple Developer Technical Support, here's their reply:

> Thank you for writing to Apple
>   Worldwide Developer Technical Support.
>   I am responding to your inquiry
>   concerning touch events in embedded
>   UITableViews.
>
> Typically this is an approach that is
>   not recommended. The issue is that
>   UITableView inherits from UIScrollView
>   and as stated in the documentation for
>   UIScrollView:
>
> "Important: You should not embed
>   UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so,
>   unexpected behavior can result because
>   touch events for the two objects can
>   be mixed up and wrongly handled."
>
> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIScrollView
>
> So that this time, there is not a
>   workaround for getting both to scroll
>   at the same time.
>
> I recommend that you file an
>   enhancement request at
>   http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/
>   detailing what you would like to see
>   us add in a future release.

Still, I think that there has to be a way to enable this functionality, although I understand that this is not recommended. In fact, Apple does not even recommend hosting UITableViews inside another UITableView, but with the exception made above, it works quite beautifully.
I'll keep this question updated with our collective findings.

EDIT: There actually is a way, detailed here: http://marcanton.io/blog/nested-orthogonal-tableviews/

Comment: It sounds like the design is one that is not typical. Is there another way to solve the problem? As I mentioned in my answer, the interpretation of touch events is very challenging based on the design of cocoa touch and even if you submit a bug to Apple, it likely won't be fixed. Are you simply trying to show a UITableView in horizontal mode? Maybe if it's broken down into pseudo requirements a new design could be brainstormed.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect the atypical nature of this setup. I thought it was a common trick, but it's not. To answer your comment: the requirement here is having a scrollable grid whose lines can be scrolled independently from each other. As each cell will be an image, it is critical that only visible cells are created and shown - in a UITableViewDataSource fashion. Smooth scrolling is also required - exactly what a UIScrollView provides. Re-implementing everything from scratch is something I'd love to avoid, if at all possible.

Comment: I'd like to add that with the above exception (you cannot scroll horizontally _and_ vertically at the same time), it is amazing how well UITouch reacts to swipes by moving the appropriate view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have to be a custom mirroring of intercepted touch events. Touch events follow the [responder chain model](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html), which means that if an object in the responder chain (the top most (outermost) view) cannot handle the event or action, it resends the message to the next responder (in this case the background `UITableView` in the chain). This is why you are seeing the horizontal events go to the horizontal `UITableView` and the vertical events going to the vertical `UITableView`. A diagonal touch event has applicable horizontal and vertical events, so the top-most view (the outer vertical UITableView) can respond to the vertical touches and swallows the event.

If you think about it, all vertical touches likely have a little bit of horizontal events (think about when you flick your finger), so there is likely some work done in the background to determine how to interpret the touch event (either as a vertical or horizontal).

I found this [tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207287/whats-the-trick-to-pass-an-event-to-the-next-responder-in-the-responder-chain) on passing events down to the next object in the responder chain. You might want to give this a try as a partial solution to your puzzle. The rest is to figure out how to capture the horizontal touch events and pass them along to the next responder.

Comment: thank you, I'm going to experiment a bit more with that and I'll report my findings. It's tricky because of the special way UIScrollViews handle touch events: it might ultimately be impossible to implement this way, but at this stage, I want to try.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I haven't played around with this kind of setup yet, but I would try to intercept touch events on the nested UITableViews and delegate any vertical movement to the outer UITableView - and vice-versa.