# How to create multiple table views inside a table in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

In my App, i need to place different different horizontal table views inside a vertical single table view. Please help me to solve this?
Thanks!!

Comment: why tableViews? why not custom views? Even you can create tableviews programatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a UI library to present Data horizontaly in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179683/looking-for-a-ui-library-to-present-data-horizontaly-in-ios) and plenty of others

Comment: Following link might be usefull to you. http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2